# Locating users within a radius of another users zip code

Tags: mysql, database, geolocation, gis, zipcode

I have a site and am allowing users to search for other users within a specified radius of their own zip code.  I first have to locate the latitude and longitude of the user and use that data to calculate and find other users.  I've prepared the following query based on the 2 required tables but am getting errors that another alias is needed.  If I hard code the values then parts of the query work find when I split them out, but with multiple joins and subqueries I've been unsuccessful.  Looking for any guidance or help. Query and table structures included below.

**Edited query and data set based on feedback.  No longer receiving errors but am not getting any data returned for the query.**

SQL Statement

```
SELECT u.username, u.zip, m.longitude,
  m.latitude,
  m.zip from users u, zipcodes m  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  s.zip,
  s.username from users s) t
 on m.zip =  t.zip
  and t.username = 'tester55'
  INNER join ( SELECT zip, city, state, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(@m.latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
    * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(@m.longitude) ) + sin( radians(@m.latitude) ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM zipcodes
HAVING distance < 5000
ORDER BY distance) as RelevantCodes
  ON (t.zip=RelevantCodes.zip)
```

User Table

```
    username     zip
-----------------------
    tester55     60608
    Tester1      60608
    iosuser1     73120
    Tester3      60608
```

Zip Code Table

```
latitude     longitude     zip
--------------------------------
41.8515      -87.6694      60608
35.5835      -97.5638      73120
36.3169      -94.1545      72758
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: Perhaps you are thinking too complicated. For example, you could replace `LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.zip, s.username from users s) t` by `LEFT JOIN users` (and replace `t` by `users` in the rest of the code, of course). But since I have given a working solution, I won't analyze your new one completely :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the time right now to work out a correct query, but I'll show what is wrong with the existing query at a first glance.

1) Regarding your actual question: The error message reads `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias` and already tells what is wrong. The subquery in the following part

```
LEFT JOIN (select s.zip,
  s.username,
  m.longitude,
  m.latitude,
  m.zip
from users s) on u.zip =  s.zip
```

needs its own alias, so that should eventually be

```
LEFT JOIN (select s.zip,
  s.username,
  m.longitude,
  m.latitude,
  m.zip
from users s) t on u.zip =  t.zip
```

(note the t after the closing parenthesis and the replacement of s.zip by t.zip). But even if you do that, you will run into problem 2 (see next section).

2) The subquery

```
(select s.zip,
        s.username,
        m.longitude,
        m.latitude,
        m.zip
        from users s)
```

will throw another error because the table m is not known within that subquery.

If you are able to work it out correctly, I suggest you edit your question and let us know the result. If not, please post a comment or edit your question, describing what other problems you encounter.

**EDIT**

I now have worked out a solution for you:

```
SELECT zipcodes.zip,
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                    cos(radians(center.latitude)) *
                    cos(radians(zipcodes.longitude ) -
                        radians(center.longitude)) +
                    sin(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                    sin(radians(center.latitude)))) AS distance FROM
  ( SELECT users.username,
           users.zip,
           zipcodes.latitude,
           zipcodes.longitude FROM
    (users JOIN zipcodes ON users.zip = zipcodes.zip)
    WHERE (username='Tester1')
  ) center, zipcodes
HAVING (distance < 5000)
ORDER BY distance;
```

This selects all ZIP codes which are within the desired distance, ordered by distance.

As you may notice, I have simplified the code. Please note also that I have tested this based on your old data (the data you have shown before your edit), but using `Tester1` instead of `tester55`.

You indeed need the `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` when filtering, so my initial statement regarding that was misleading. The reason is that MySQL does not allow computed columns (in this case: distance) in `WHERE` clauses, but in `HAVING` clauses. This is non-standard behavior; usually, you have to solve this problem another way. I won't elaborate on that because it is an additional possibly worrying thing which is not closely related to your original question.

**EDIT 2**

Finally, here is the version which gives the username in addition:

```
SELECT zipcodes.zip,
       users.username,
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                    cos(radians(center.latitude)) *
                    cos(radians(zipcodes.longitude ) -
                        radians(center.longitude)) +
                    sin(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                    sin(radians(center.latitude)))) AS distance FROM
  ( ( SELECT users.username,
             users.zip,
             zipcodes.latitude,
             zipcodes.longitude FROM
      (users JOIN zipcodes ON users.zip = zipcodes.zip)
      WHERE (username='Tester1')
    ) center, zipcodes) INNER JOIN users ON zipcodes.zip = users.zip
WHERE (users.username <> 'Tester1')
HAVING (distance < 5000)
ORDER BY distance;
```

Please note that you need the third from last line to filter out the user you are calculating the distances for. If you don't do that, the result will include a row with the user itself (in this case: `Tester1`) and a distance of (nearly) `0`.

**EDIT 3**

The following is a version as requested by the comments below (desired seeking radius stored as additional field `seekingdistance` in table `users`):

```
SELECT zipcodes.zip,
       users.username,
       center.seekingdistance,
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                    cos(radians(center.latitude)) *
                    cos(radians(zipcodes.longitude ) -
                        radians(center.longitude)) +
                    sin(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                    sin(radians(center.latitude)))) AS distance FROM
  ( ( SELECT users.username,
             users.zip,
             users.seekingdistance,
             zipcodes.latitude,
             zipcodes.longitude FROM
      (users JOIN zipcodes ON users.zip = zipcodes.zip)
      WHERE (username='Tester1')
    ) center, zipcodes) INNER JOIN users ON zipcodes.zip = users.zip
WHERE (users.username <> 'Tester1')
HAVING (distance < center.seekingdistance)
ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: thank you for your guidance.  You feedback helped me to get past the initial error now I'm dealing with errors stating duplicate zip columns.  I'm using your remaining tips to try to come up with a solution but am honestly stumped.

Comment: I'll eventually try to work out a correct query, but please edit your question and provide correct data. The query you have shown so far won't show any results since `tester55's` zip is not in the `zipcodes` table. While this does not prevent us from working out a syntactically correct query, it will prevent us from checking if that query yields meaningful results.

Comment: Thank you.  I've revised the query and am now error free but it's not returning any data.  I've updated the question with the revised query and correct data with the sample set.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was way off.  You're awesome and a genius.  :-)

Comment: Binarus let me know if I need to post another question.  I've included 'seekingdistance' as a column in my user table.  I'd like to use that in place of the 5000 so the user can decide how far away to search.  I edited the query to reflect that but am getting a 'column not found.'  Let me know if I need to post another question.  Sorry for not mentioning it before.  Thank you again.

Comment: @techgirl08 Thanks for the compliment. You don't need to post a new question if your additional question is reasonably related to your original one. But a tip for next time: If you edit your question, and if there are already answers or comments, then please don't edit these parts of the question the answer and comments refer to. Instead, leave that parts as they are and just add your edits at the end. Otherwise, later readers (SO is all about sharing knowledge) won't be able to understand the comments or answers (because they refer to things that don't exist any more).

Comment: @techgirl08 Your additional question: It might not be as easy as it seems. Let us assume that user A has chosen a seeking distance of 200, user B has chosen a seeking distance of 100, and the actual distance between them is 150. When user A searches, he will find user B. But user B probably does not want to be found by user A because user A is too far away. So we first will have to define how that seeking distance should work. Replacing the 5000 by the *searching* user's seeking distance is not difficult; I haven't thought yet about replacing it by the *to-be-searched* users' seeking distance.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I'm new to SO so it's good to know the etiquette.

Comment: @@Binarus Thanks for the additional thoughts and possible use case.  I thought about it and I'm actually not going to limit the view based on the to-be-searched users' seeking distance.  So User B may show up in User A's results but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks @Binarus - You're the real MVP.  :-)